# Why is chaining iterables this complicated? Simplify this code

Tags: python-3.x, generator, python-itertools, chaining, iterable

I want to chain multiple iterables, everything with lazy evaluation (speed is crucial), to do the following:

- read many integers from a single huge line of stdin
- split() that line
- convert the resulting strings to int
- compute the diff between successive ints
- ... and some further things not shown here

The real example is more complex, here's a simplified example:

Here's a sample line of stdin:
2 13 4 16 16 15 22 17 8 8 7 6

(For debugging purposes, `instream` below might point to sys.stdin, or an opened filehandle)

You can't simply chain generators since `map()` returns a (lazily-evaluated) list:

```
import itertools
gen1 = map(int, (map(str.split, instream))) # CAN'T CHAIN DIRECTLY
```

The least complicated working solution I found is this, can it surely not be simplified?

```
gen1 = map(int, itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain(map(str.split, instream))))
```

Why the hell do I need to chain `itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain` just to process the result from `map(str.split, instream)` - it sort of defeats the purpose?
Is manually defining my generators faster?

Answer (score 2):

An explicit ("manual") generator expression should be preferred over using `map` and `filter`. It is more readable to most people, and more flexible.

If I understand your question, this generator expression does what you need:

```
gen1 = ( int(x) for line in instream for x in line.split() )
```

Comment: But I also said I absolutely needed lazy evaluation, and forming the list `line.split()` slows things down. Take it that `map(str.split, instream)` is your startpoint.

Comment: @smci: `map(str.split, instream)` forms exactly the same lists that `line.split()` does when iterated over; `map` can't make `str.split` lazy.

Comment: Ok. Can you answer the part about why I need the crappy `itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain(...` ?

Comment: @smci: `itertools.chain` with one argument basically does nothing (it returns something equivalent to its argument).  Simplify to `itertools.chain.from_iterable(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your generator by hand:

```
import string

def gen1(stream):
    # presuming that stream is of type io.TextIOBase


    s = ""
    c = stream.read(1)  
    while len(c)>0:

        if (c not in string.digits):
            if len(s) > 0:
                i = int(s)
                yield i
                s = ""
        else:
            s += c

        c = stream.read(1)

    if len(s) > 0:
        i = int(s)
        yield i 


import io
g = gen1(io.StringIO("12 45  6 7 88"))
for x in g:    # dangerous if stream is unlimited
    print(x)
```

Which is certainly not the most beautiful code, but it does what you want.
Explanations:

If your input is indefinitely long you have to read it in chunks (or character wise).
Whenever you encounter a non-digit (whitespace), you convert the characters you have read until that point into an integer and yield it.
You also have to consider what happens when you reach the EOF.
My implementation is probably not very well performed, due to the fact that I'm reading char-wise. Using chunks one could speed it up significantly.

**EDIT** as to why your approach will never work:

```
map(str.split, instream)
```

does simply not do what you appear to think it does. `map` applies the given function `str.split` to each element of the iterator given as the second parameter. In your case that is a stream, i.e. a file object, in the case of sys.stdin specifically a io.TextIOBase object. Which indeed can be iterated over. Line by line, which emphatically is NOT what you want! In effect you iterate over your input line by line and split each line into words. The map generator iterates over (many) lists of words NOT over A list of words. Which is why you have to chain them together to get a single list to iterate on.

Also, the `itertools.chain()` in `itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain(map(...)))` is redundant. `itertools.chain` chains its arguments (each an inalterable object) together into one iterator. You only give it one argument so there is nothing to chain together, it basically returns the map object unchanged.
`itertools.chain.from_iterable()` on the other hand takes one argument, which is expected to be an iterator of iterators (e.g. a list of lists) and flattens it into one iterator (list).

**EDIT2**

```
import io, itertools

instream = io.StringIO("12 45 \n 66 7 88")
gen1 = itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, instream))
gen2 = map(int, gen1)
list(gen2)
```

returns

```
[12, 45, 66, 7, 88]
```

Comment: The code I posted **does** work: `gen1 = map(int, itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain(map(str.split, instream))))`

Comment: and no, the `itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain(` is **not** redundant; the code breaks without it. Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: @smci: yes it does, but it doesn't do what you describe you want it to do.